# How to set some extra information for each item on GridView in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridview

I have a GridView in which every item must have an ID other than its position in the grid so that I can pass that id using Intents to another activity?
How can I specify this extra parameter and how can I access it inside `onItemClick` method?

**Edit:**

```
int catID = cu.getInt(0);
myView.setTag((Object) catID);
```

That's how I use `setTag` method.

```
Intent categoryActivity = new Intent(getParent(), CategoryActivity.class);
categoryActivity.putExtra("itemId", (Integer) v.getTag());
startChildActivity("CategoryActivity", categoryActivity);
```

And this how I use `getTag`.
I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `View.setTag()` and `View.getTag()` methods for this.

Comment: You have to sure that you set tag for the same object, where you set click listener

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast the int to `Object` but should actually store it as an Integer: myView.setTag(new Integer(catID));